# how to open project with Java EE Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Like this:

[image]

the "open project" item's color is grey.

Comment: This is a bit confusing if you are not used to Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you want to [Import a Project to Eclipse From an Archive File](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/import_export/).

Comment: how in the world did you know he wanted to do that from his question?

Comment: @SB: Eclipse has projects. I guessed he was looking for a File => Open and the correct way to do it, is a project import :)

Answer (score 7):

**Project > Open Project** and **Project > Close Project** may no be what you think, they apply to projects that are already in the workspace and are closed/open respectively. From the [Eclipse documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-47.htm):

> When a project is closed, it can no longer be changed in the Workbench and its resources no longer appear in the Workbench, but they do still reside on the local file system. Closed projects require less memory. Also, since they are not examined during builds, closing a project can improve build time.

You are probably looking for **File > New > Project** that would open the following wizard (select the type of project you want to create and follow the steps):

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/images/Image247_projsel_wiz.png))</sub>

To import an existing Eclipse project, use **File > Import > Existing Project into Workspace**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first create a project using File -> New Project.  Then the project you've created must be closed before you can then open it.